# Load data from json file to angular module

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm trying to load data into my angular module from json file but instead of data i'm getting this.

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope, $http)
 {
   $http.get('bookData.json').then(function(response){

      $scope.books = response.data;
    });
 });
```

And in my view displaying data as:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <div>{{"Book details"}}</div>
     <div>
       <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="x in books">
           <td>x.bookid</td>
           <td>x.author</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But i'm getting output as:

```
   Book details

x.bookid    x.author
x.bookid    x.author
x.bookid    x.author
x.bookid    x.author
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZqcnwOKZUdUo5eDIdjlh?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your logic with `{{` and `}}` to make it recognisable by angular. Otherwise it'll print out as just plain text.

e.g

```
<td>{{x.bookid}}</td>
<td>{{x.author}}</td>
```

Comment: Yeah It works !! it was such a silly mistake. Thanku so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        <H1>Book details</H1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in books">
                <td>{{x.bookid}}</td>
                <td>{{x.author}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```